# How to specify case insensitivity in AWK within for loop?

Tags: awk

I have an awk line :

```
awk -F'/|//'  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="CUST")break;print $(i)}'
```

I want the `CUST` to be case insensitive and I am using `($i==CUST)` because the file contains words like `CUSTOMER`, which should not get matched.

I tried using Character class like: `if($i=="[Cc][Uu][Ss][Tt]")` but that throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is you are doing string comparison with `==` when the regular expression comparison operator is `~` and your regular expression string should be like `/^[Cc][Uu][Ss][Tt]$/` *(notice the anchors `^` and `$` stop overmatching)*:

```
awk -F'/|//' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^[Cc][Uu[Ss][tT]$/)break; print $i}'
```

Better approachs would be to use the [`IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) variable or the [`tolower, toupper`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) functions.

Comment: Will not this match both `CUST` and `CUSTOMER`? If I am correct OP does not like to match on `CUSTOMER`

Comment: @Jotne right but `IGNORECASE` or one of the string functions is a better approach, was just pointing out the actual error in the OPs approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`

```
toupper($i)
```

or

```
tolower($i)
```

Like this:

```
awk -F'/|//'  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (tolower($i) == "cust")break; print $i}'
```